# Wireless tethering between two Android devices

Tags: wifi-tethering

I have two Androids. The first one has an Internet connection. I want to share this Internet connection to my second device. I installed wireless tether app to my first device but my second device didn't find this tether network. What setting should I change?

Comment: Is your phone, by chance, creating an ad hoc wireless network when you use the tethering app?

Comment: Also, be sure that the device creating the hotspot is either rooted, or you've purchased a tethering service plan from your provider.

Comment: Koush (creator of ClockworkMod) came up with a way to "hide" the tethering in action - I remember reading about it on Google+, it hides something, so that carrier does not recognize that tethering is in place, that's what he claimed... am in EU, so tethering is fine for me, I do know US Carriers are pretty strict about it and hate it! Linky https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.tether

Answer (score 2):

Your Android phone (if that is what you mean by having two Android), should have a setting for Wireless Tethering. Open the Settings -> Wireless option in your Android phone and there you will get the option.

You will need to provide a name to the network and then try to search for that name in the other phone, as a New Wireless Network. Also, your Data provider should have allowed tethering on your phone; they sometimes block tethering where unlimited data plans or plans with high data usage are provided.

Also, could you provide some more details on how you went about doing the same, that might help in providing a more useful answer.

Comment: Wireless tethering is an android tool and it has nothing to do with 'Data provider'. Some Data providers are blocking tethering APPS in the Android Market and NOT THE TETHERING. If you have tethering app and working data plan then it should work.