# How to make cell phone using GPRS/3G a WiFi-Hotspot

Tags: applications, 2.3-gingerbread, wi-fi, wifi-hotspot, gprs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to share internet among 2 android devices?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4117/how-to-share-internet-among-2-android-devices)
>   [Can we use an Android phone as a Wi-Fi repeater?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12616/can-we-use-an-android-phone-as-a-wi-fi-repeater)

I have an android cell phone (Samsung Galaxy S Advance) running on Android 2.3.6. I am interested in converting my cell phone to a WiFi-Hotspot so that I can use the GPPRS/3G from my phone to access internet on other WiFi-enabled devices. Any android applications that might help to do this?

Comment: Have you looked at the questions in the [wifi-hotspot](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wifi-hotspot) and [wifi-tethering](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wifi-tethering) tags at all? Did you do a search? This has been covered in a lot of forms for a lot of devices. If you can provide some context of what you have tried then it would be helpful.

Comment: Potential duplicates: [Is there a way to enable WiFi-tethering without root access?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/253), [Wireless tethering between two Android devices](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/16330), [How to share internet among 2 android devices?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/4117), [How do I share my wifi with my ipod or netbook](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/43)